# Ignoring/filtering nil

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

Is there an operator that can filter `nil`?  The closest I've come is the solution mentioned here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/209#issuecomment-150842686

Relevant excerpt:

```
public protocol OptionalType {
    func hasValue() -> Bool
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    public func hasValue() -> Bool {
        return (self != nil)
    }
}

public extension ObservableType where E: OptionalType {
    @warn_unused_result(message="http://git.io/rxs.uo")
    public func notNil() -> Observable<E> {
        return self.filter { $0.hasValue() }
    }
}
```

However, after `.notNil()`, `E` is still optional, so subsequent chained operators still see `self` as `Observer<E>` where `E` is optional.  So I'm still needing an extra operator that does:

```
.map { (username: String?) -> String in
    return username!
}
```

I must be missing something. This seems like it would be a very common need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

checkout `unwrap` at https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwift-Ext :)

or https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxOptional

For now, you should use `RxOptional` for your personal needs
However, `RxSwift-Ext` will be growth exponentially in next 2-3 months :)

P/S: these guys (i'm talking about owners of these repos) chat with each others daily on `RxSwift`'s slack :)

Answer (score 39):

In RxSwift 5 it's possible using `compactMap` from core library:

```
observable.compactMap { $0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

- To filter out the `nil` values, use [RxSwiftExt.unwrap()](https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxSwiftExt#unwrap)
- And to filter only the `nil` values, simply do this:

```swift
observableContainingNils.filter { $0 == .none }
```